Matter after Commission to google fabric not able to find device in Goggle home App
I commission the matter device using goggle play service using following function
after commission success not able to find commissioned device in goggle home app.  is there any Method need to call after commission success to register device in google home app, I want to commission matter device in goggle fabric from my app and device can control by using goggle Home app
private fun commissionDevice() {
val request: CommissioningRequest = CommissioningRequest.builder().build()
Matter.getCommissioningClient(this)
    .commissionDevice(request)
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        commissioningLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result).build())
    }

}
After commission success matter device should be visible and Controle by using goggle home app

Try to make sure to commission the devices to Google fabric, or on a shared fabric. If the devices are commissioned to a 3rd party matter fabric that Google don’t have access to, it is not going to be able to control them.
